# PySpark - map with lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark

I'm facing an issue when mixing python map and lambda functions on a Spark environment.

Given df1, my source dataframe:

```
Animals     | Food      | Home
----------------------------------
Monkey      | Banana    | Jungle
Dog         | Meat      | Garden
Cat         | Fish      | House
Elephant    | Banana    | Jungle
Lion        | Meat      | Desert
```

I want to create another dataframe df2. It will contain two columns with a row per column of df1 (3 in my example).
The first column would contain the name of df1 columns. The second column would contain an array of elements with the most occurrences (n=3 in the example below) and the count.

```
Column      | Content
-----------------------------------------------------------
Animals     | [("Cat", 1), ("Dog", 1), ("Elephant", 1)]
Food        | [("Banana", 2), ("Meat", 2), ("Fish", 1)]
Home        | [("Jungle", 2), ("Desert", 1), ("Garden", 1)]
```

I tried to do it with python list, map and lambda functions but I had conflicts with PySpark functions:

```
def transform(df1):
    # Number of entry to keep per row
    n = 3
    # Add a column for the count of occurence
    df1 = df1.withColumn("future_occurences", F.lit(1))

    df2 = df1.withColumn("Content",
        F.array(
            F.create_map(
                lambda x: (x,
                    [
                        str(row[x]) for row in df1.groupBy(x).agg(
                            F.sum("future_occurences").alias("occurences")
                        ).orderBy(
                            F.desc("occurences")
                        ).select(x).limit(n).collect()
                    ]
                ), df1.columns
            )
        )
    )
    return df2
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <function <lambda> at 0x7fc844430410> of type <type 'function'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This can be done, but it's not really the type of problem that spark is designed for. You can treat each column independently and `union` the results. How do you break ties? Why is it `Cat`, `Dog`, `Elephant` when the other two animals also have a count of 1?

Comment: @PentaKill I prefer to post my code to illustrate the problem I'm facing. I don't understand why you say it is useless.

Comment: @pault thanks for your comment. I'm new to spark so I still need to learn. Yes I guess I could treat column independently but I wasn't sure it was the best solution. I break ties with alphabetic order. This is why I didn't display Lion and Monkey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution, in which the `Content` column will be an array of `StructType` with two named fields: `Content` and `count`.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_list, desc, lit, struct
from functools import reduce 

def transform(df, n):
    return reduce(
        lambda a, b: a.unionAll(b),
        (
            df.groupBy(c).count()\
                .orderBy(desc("count"), c)\
                .limit(n)\
                .withColumn("Column", lit(c))\
                .groupBy("Column")\
                .agg(
                    collect_list(
                        struct(
                            col(c).cast("string").alias("Content"), 
                            "count")
                    ).alias("Content")
                )
            for c in df.columns
        )
    )
```

This function will iterate through each of the columns in the input DataFrame, `df`, and count the occurrence of each value. Then we `orderBy` the count (descending) and the column value it self (alphabetically) and keep only the first `n` rows (`limit(n)`).

Next, collect the values into an array of structs and finally `union` together the results for each column. Since the `union` requires each DataFrame to have the same schema, you will need to cast the column value to a string.

```python
n = 3
df1 = transform(df, n)
df1.show(truncate=False)
#+-------+------------------------------------+
#|Column |Content                             |
#+-------+------------------------------------+
#|Animals|[[Cat,1], [Dog,1], [Elephant,1]]    |
#|Food   |[[Banana,2], [Meat,2], [Fish,1]]    |
#|Home   |[[Jungle,2], [Desert,1], [Garden,1]]|
#+-------+------------------------------------+
```

This isn't *exactly* the same output that you asked for, but it will probably be sufficient for your needs. (Spark doesn't have tuples in the way you described.) Here's the new schema:

```python
df1.printSchema()
#root
# |-- Column: string (nullable = false)
# |-- Content: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- Content: string (nullable = true)
# |    |    |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

Comment: thanks for your solution which seems to fully answer my needs. However it leads to an error `Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. array<struct<Content:boolean,count:bigint>> <> array<struct<Content:string,count:bigint>> at the second column of the 2th table`. I don't understand where the boolean type comes from.

Comment: excellent! thanks a lot! Only thing is I've got `Animals|[[Content: Cat, count: 1], [Content: Dog, count: 1], [Content; Elephant, count: 1]]`
Is it possible to remove the title in the struct? Even if I remove the alias there is still a title.

Comment: @Maxbester you can change the `struct` to `array` (after `from pyspark.sql.functions import array`) which would leave you with a `WrappedArray`. I'm not sure why this matters to you - what's the end goal?

Comment: ok I will try. Sorry I thought I explained the goal in my initial question. Actually the purpose is to validate a dataset creation. I want to make sure data is relevant in each column. Obviously my dataset is much bigger than the one I gave as an example.